# How to generate TPC-DS query for sql-server from templates

Tags: sql-server, benchmark

I know that dsqgen is used to transform the query templates into executable SQL. But when I type in the command line: "dsqgen /directory query_templates /template query1.tpl /dialect sqlserver /scale 5", there's an error that "Substitution 'STATE' is used before being initialized". I also copied the ansi.tpl and tpcds.idx files in the same directory as dsqgen.exe because dsqgen always read these two files. Anyone has any idea how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can download fix error "STATE" and endcoding dump data to database at https://github.com/grahn/tpcds-kit

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, the first thing I tried was to erase query1.tpl from the templates.list, but then I got a similar error for query2.tpl but referring to the substitution '_END'.

I looked at the template and realized that the variable was never used, then I looked in the QGEN.doc guide and read that the variables are automatically set for 
use of benchmark sponsors. So after struggling with it, I decided to make a simple solution: I changed every template (with a script) and added the line:

```
define _END = "";
```

At the beginning of each of them, and voilà, problem solved! However, I was still getting similar errors for some queries (like query1, where the variable STATE is referred but not used), so I just took those queries out of the list and I was finally able to generate 68 out of 99 of the queries. I guess that for tpcds toolkit v1.1.0 apparently there are errors in the query templates.

Hope it works for you, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: instead of adding `define _END = "";` to each template, it can be added into dialect (`netezza.tpl` for example). This has fixed compilation of all the templates on the latest tpc-ds 1.3.1.